# JNA cannot find function

Tags: java, c, dll, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror

JNA and DLLs are completely new territory for me...  I have a custom DLL that has a function with this declaration:

```
int myfunc (const char*);
```

The dll compiles fine under MinGW with the following command:

```
>gcc -shared -omydll.dll mydll.c -lgdi32
```

However, loading it with JNA fails because it can't find the function within the DLL.

```
public interface mydll extends StdCallLibrary {
  mydll INSTANCE = (mydll)Native.loadLibrary("mydll", mydll.class);
  int myfunc (String arg);
  }
```

I did some research and it seems that this particular error has something to do with the calling procedure of the DLL functions.  I've seen the `__stdcall` and the `__cdecl` procedures.  I also saw that many DLL functions put `__declspec(dllexport)` in front of their function declarations/implementations (i have no idea what this means or what it does).  So, since JNA seems to like the `__stdcall` procedure better, now my function looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myfunc (const char*);
```

Which looks super-complicated, but does no better than anything else i've tried.  Using a HashMap to add the underscore prefix and the @4 suffix didn't work either:

```
mydll INSTANCE = (mydll)Native.loadLibrary("mydll", mydll.class, new HashMap () {{
  add("myfunc", "_myfunc@4");
  }});
```

The JNA documentation has been absolutely no help.  I honestly have no idea what i'm doing anymore.

Comment: What particular error are you getting, literally?

Comment: Have you set `-Djna.library.path=<path location of your DLLs/libraries>`?

Comment: You should provide the actual exception you are seeing, which will indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: Follow Java conventions and name classes with a capital letter and mixed case (e.g. MyDLL.class).  When you don't, it indicates you're new at Java and not really paying attention.

Comment: Don't use stdcall unless you have a specific reason to do so.  If you *do* use stdcall, you can avoid the function mapper by telling gcc to include undecorated names with "-Wl,add-stdcall-alias".

Comment: Please refer to the GCC/MingW documentation for information how to properly generate a DLL on Windows.  Properly building a shared library on any given platform is outside the scope of JNA (although you can certainly learn from its Makefile).

Comment: I know that JNA can find my DLL because it's in the same directory as my .class file.  If i rename/move my DLL i get a "Cannot find DLL" error instead of the "Cannot find function _within_ DLL" that i'm stumped by.  @technomage, thanks for the "-Wl,add-stdcall-alias" switch; i'll try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that i was building my DLL just fine, and JNA was finding my DLL just fine as well; i made an error in determining how the compiler mangled my symbols.  Functions i named like `myfunc` were exported as `myfunc@8` or `myfunc@32` depending on how many bytes they took as arguments.  Here's the code i used in my JNA project:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;
//
public class Test
  {
  public interface mydll extends StdCallLibrary
    {
    mydll INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("mydll", mydll.class, new HashMap {{
      put("myfunc", "myfunc@8");
      //Other functions
      }});
    public int myfunc (long arg);
    //Other functions
    }
  //
  public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println
      (mydll.INSTANCE.myfunc((long)0x23A3920F)); //Or whatever
    return 0;
    }
  }
```

My c code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myfunc (__int64);
/* Other functions */

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myfunc (__int64 arg)
  {
  /* Whatever */
  return return_value;
  }
```

GCC was happy with just the `-shared` switch and linking against the proper libraries, like in my original question.  **I highly recommend downloading [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) so you can find out exactly what your function names are.**

Comment: JNA provides a StdCallFunctionMapper to do what you've been doing manually, although I'd still recommend just dropping the std call and using the standard C calling convention instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how the test library within JNA is built (native/Makefile).  Following that example will indicate proper export signatures and calling conventions.

`__declspec(dllexport)` indicates that the function name should be exported.

`__stdcall` is what is used by most MS APIs; you normally have no reason to use it in your own code, as it only complicates linking with its mangling of names.

When actually compiling (and linking), you need to tell GCC that you're building a shared library.  Simply naming the file "*.dll" isn't sufficient.

```
gcc -o mydll.dll -shared mydll.c
```

You may need one or more `-l<libname>` options at the end depending on what native libraries you're accessing.